# Add class to elements which already have a class

Tags: javascript, class

I have a group of divs which I'm dynamically generating when a button is clicked with the class, "brick". This gives them dimension and starting position of top: 0. I'm trying to get them to animate to the bottom of the view using a css transition with a second class assignment which gives them a bottom position: 0;. Can't figure out the syntax for adding a second class to elements with a pre-existing class. On inspection they only show the original class of, "brick".

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="button" >Click Me</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vmax;
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
}

.brick {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 10vmax;
  width: 20vmax;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.drop {
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom 0;
}
```

The offending JS:

```
var brickCount = function() { 
  var count = prompt("How many boxes you lookin' for?");  
  for(var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    var newBrick = document.createElement("div");
    newBrick.className="brick";
    document.querySelector("#container")
   .appendChild(newBrick);
  }
};

var getBricks = function(){
 document.getElementByClass("brick");
};

var changeColor = function(){
  getBricks.style.backgroundColor = 
 '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
};

var addDrop = function() {
  getBricks.brick = "getBricks.brick" + " drop"; 
};

var multiple = function() {
  brickCount();
   getBricks();
   changeColor();
   addDrop();
};


document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {multiple();};
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanna use pure javaScript** [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

HTML:

```
<div id="testdiv" class="brick"></div>
```

javaScript:

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").classList.add("anotherclass");

alert(document.getElementById("testdiv").className);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dinizworld/PfWqy/1/

**If you wanna use jQuery** [addClass](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp)

HTML:

```
<div id="testdiv" class="brick"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".brick").addClass("numbertwo");

alert($("#testdiv").prop("class"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dinizworld/UN4gK/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to an element by doing the following:

```
element.className = element.className + " drop";
```

This is just a single string of classnames, so if you're appending, don't forget to add the space.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className